# How to convert a object to nullable double during runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to add a object into list of nullable double List in runtime.But if I give simply Convert.ToDouble(obj),then I will get 0 instead of null.So I have used coalescing operator.But I cannot add object into list.

```
        IList<double?> list = new List<double?>();
        int a = 10;
        object b=null;
        list.Add(2);
        list.Add(b ??Convert.ToDouble(b));
        list.Add(Convert.ToDouble(a));
        list.Add(null);
```

Comment: If you want a null to be present when b is null, you definitely don't want to use null coalescing like that. If not, please explain clearer

Comment: Then how to achieve above scenario in big projects while using concepts like reflection?

Comment: How does reflection come to this? It has nothing to do with using the coalescing operator wrong, or using nullables

Answer (score 1):

You can cast object to nullable double to add it to nullable double list.

```
list.Add((double?)b );
```

Comment: does it not affect the performance while using Reflection for converting the value during runtime?

Comment: this is a correct answer. after you boxed Nullable<double> to an object only way to regain it's type information is casting back to Nullable<double> as Adil mentioned above.
You don't really have a choice, type cast will happen one way or another. If you want to avoid type casts it would probably be better idea to avoid casting to object to begin with if at all possible.

Comment: What do you mean by reflection? If you are asking about the cast then you have to convert the object to nullable double and you can not avoid in given circumstances.

Comment: Adil-Reflection is used to get the data about our code during runtime by accessing metadata of our code